# How to install centos packages in puppet?

Tags: centos, vagrant, puppet

I setup a class in my site.pp

```
class packages {
    Package { ensure => 'installed' }
    package { 'python-devel': }
    package { 'blas-devel': }
    package { 'lapack-devel': }
}
```

but nothing seems to be happening?
when i run

```
pip install scipy
```

I still get that `Python.h` cannot be compiled so I take it python devel didn't install

Answer (score 1):

You have *defined* class '`packages`', but you do not show that class being assigned to any node.  That's like writing a function but never calling it.

You need to *declare* that class to assign it to specific nodes or to all nodes (depending on the context of the declaration).  There are a few different forms for that, but about the simplest thing you could do would be to add ...

```
include 'packages'
```

... on the line after the closing brace of your class definition.

The result will still be in rather poor form, as classes should be defined in modules, not in `site.pp`, and declarations rarely should appear at top scope (outside any node block, class definition, or type definition), but it will instruct Puppet that when it runs, it should ensure that the packages you specify are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the way you wrote the code for the modules doesn't look right.  I would try something more like the following

```
class 'my-python' {
  package {'python-devel':
     ensure => installed,
  }
  package {'lapack-devel':
     ensure => installed,
  }
  package {'python-devel':
     ensure => installed,
  }
}
```

you define each of the packages within the class as seperate package resources.  Then you need to 'include mypython' in your site.pp for the node you want to install them on.  Run puppet and you should be good.

Comment: The code the OP presented is fine.  He declares resource defaults for `Package` resources, and then relies on them for his declarations of specific `Package` instances.  Your code is semantically equivalent to his.

Comment: after I changed `'my-python'` to just `my-python` it worked I don't know why it didn't like the quotes. For ref I was originally copying: http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/install-multiple-packages.html